# Optimize Routing Table

Tags: routing

I have a (probably simple) question, for my studies I need to optimize the following static routing table:

```
Net           Mask              Gateway          Interface
10.1.0.0      255.255.0.0       10.1.0.1         if0
10.130.0.0    255.255.0.0       10.130.0.1       if0
10.140.0.0    255.255.0.0       10.140.0.1       if1
10.1.60.0     255.255.255.0     10.1.60.1        if2
10.60.0.0     255.255.0.0       10.60.0.1        if0
10.120.0.0    255.255.0.0       10.120.0.1       if1
```

Is it correct that without further information, I can't reduce the entries in this table?

All I can see is that at least three networks are indireclty connected, the network 10.60.0.0/24 is a subnet of 10.1.0.0/16 but they are on different interfaces.

My solution so far is that, when we do not know on which networks the interfaces if0 and if1 are connected. And we also do not know where all the listed gateways can route to, this table can not be simplified!?

Comment: Unfortunately, all"_education, certification, or homework_" questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the data you provide is not a routing table.
A routing table entry has (basically) 3 components:

- a network address
- a prefix length or subnet mask (those are two methods to write the same thing)
- either a next-hop IP or an interface

The "gateway" notion is for host. Since the Gateway column list an IP that belongs to the network, I assume it is actually the IP assigned to the router interface (I.E. it is the IP that the connected hosts uses as a gateway). But it is irrelevant for routing decision performed by the router.
So we have to assume the interface column is what matters.

Second, it's not clear what the intended result is but this could be a solution:

```
Network       Mask              Interface
10.0.0.0      255.0.0.0         if0
10.1.60.0     255.255.255.0     if2
10.120.0.0    255.255.0.0       if1
10.140.0.0    255.255.0.0       if1
```

But it is a very poorly phrased exercise...

Comment: Very helpful! I'm overall not very happy with this course... :). To state the fact that there can be an interface OR a next hop, did it. This solved the knot in my brain, thanks!